# Making sense of low DNA match for half-siblings

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

My DNA match on Ancestry was thought to be my half sister.

After my test came back, 713 cMs across 20 segments, 10% shared DNA, longest segment 136, that says my Grandfather would be her father, but my father makes more sense.

I have read that females carry more DNA from their fathers than Males do.

If my full sister gets tested, is there a possibility that hers may come up higher into the half sibling?

Is there any possible way with my numbers I could be her half sibling?

Also, what about getting my daughter tested?

She and my sister are the only females in the family on my fathers side.

Answer (score 2):

Males and females do inherit DNA differently from their fathers, but not in a way that affects the *autosomal* tests that are used for the comparisons. The difference is in the inheritance of an X or Y chromosome, which are *sex chromosomes*; they are not *autosomal chromosomes*, so they play no role in the total match measurement of 713 cMs.

Testing your full sister and comparing to the two current measurements might provide some insight to the relationships, but testing your daughter will not.

We recommend viewing the probabilities of relationships for your match via this link: https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/713.  You will see that half-sibling is not considered to be among the possibilities for that level of autosomal sharing.